# Html form to local xml file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml

I'm trying to make a simple form that adds user input to a local xml file. Basically, I need to input a name and a proffesion.
The xml file looks something like this:

```
<mainNode>
<name>Jeff</name>
<proffesion>Dog Trainer</proffesion>
</mainNode>
```

But I need some method (either with jQuery or javascript) to populate or add to the existing file (example.xml) using that form instead of creating a new xml file or replacing the nodes. I would show I've tried so far, but i've tried so many examples I can't even decide what to show (but if necessary I'll edit this post ). Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks ! :)

Comment: Form needs to submit to your back end server side code where you would use an xml library to read and modify existing

Comment: I already have a way to read and display the xml data into an html file  ( it's a super simple ajax code that finds the nodes and 
appends them to whatever divs I choose )- I don't need to process the data in complicated ways just display it , as I only need 2 fields or maybe 3 at best.

Comment: Fine but you can only write updates to that xml file using server side code

Comment: I think I understand. You mean, the code that handles the updates for the xml has to be hosted on some server? If so, that shouldn't be a problem. I'm mainly trying to avoid dealing with databeses, that's why I've mentioned a "local" file, maybe I should've been more clear, sorry :) . I don't need this to be handled on a pc, server side is fine, as long as I don't need to deal with asp, or sql. Thanks for your time ! :D

Comment: Even with local file you need to run a loclhost server. Browser security blocks direct file access for obvious reasons